# How does one get first place in Clan Games

Tags: clash-of-clans

With the recent update, Clan Games is added. Basically, in this event, you do tasks and get points for every successful completion of each task, with points maxed at 500.

In a clan, members can check the leaderboards to see who has the most points collected in their clan. However, with a max of 500, and multiple people with 500 points, it's hard to see how you actually get first. It is not time-related (i.e first to 500 is automatic first place) as a new number one appeared in my clan.

So how do you actually end up in first place *in your clan* for Clan Games assuming there are multiple people that have reached the point cap of 500 (i.e if  players A, B, C, and D have met the cap, who ends up in first)?

Answer (score 1):

The first person to reach 500 cap should win and end up in first it's just who got in first the quickest.
says ex-clash of clans player(that's how it worked for me.)

Comment: But this was clearly not the case

Answer (score 1):

There are some working theories about this on [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/ClashOfClans).
Some popular ones are:

- Based on how long you have been in the clan (without leaving)
- Based on the points, but also by how much you exceed the cap (say you are on 490 and then do another challenge for 100 points, then you are technically 90 over the cap)
- How much time you had left to complete every challenge (in percentages or something)
- By difficulty of the tasks completed

So nobody knows for sure (yet). 
You can find more working theories on [the Clash Of Clans subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/ClashOfClans) if you want